# Multiple Columns from float to date Pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a data frame with data imported as float64.  I have been able to convert 1 column to a date, but when I try to scale that for multiple, I get:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be 
specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

This works for  for 1 Column:

```
df['Col4'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col4'].astype(str), format = '%Y%m%d')

df.head().dtypes
Out[151]: 
Col1            float64
Col2            object
Col3            float64
Col4     datetime64[ns]
Col5            float64
Col6            float64
dtype: object
```

I tried the below for multiple columns and got denied, any help appreciated:

```
"""
df[['Col4', 'Col5']] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Col4' , 'Col5']].astype(str), format = '%Y%m%d')
df.head().dtypes
"""
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
cols = ['Col4', 'Col5']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.astype(str), format = '%Y%m%d'))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col4':[20150101.0, 20150102],
                   'Col5':[20160101.0, 20160102],
                   'Col1':[1,2]})
print (df)
   Col1        Col4        Col5
0     1  20150101.0  20160101.0
1     2  20150102.0  20160102.0

cols = ['Col4', 'Col5']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.astype(str), format = '%Y%m%d'))
print (df)
   Col1       Col4       Col5
0     1 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
1     2 2015-01-02 2016-01-02
```

---

```
cols = ['Col4', 'Col5']
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%Y%m%d')
print (df)
   Col1       Col4       Col5
0     1 2015-01-01 2016-01-01
1     2 2015-01-02 2016-01-02
```

Comment: Good news is you got me over the hump ... bad news is I now am rolling and up past my bed time.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Super, I think it is good feeling if it works ;) Good night ;)